# how to add query parameters on react start up without react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not sure whether this question may sound strange but I am wondering whether there is a way I can add query params to the URL when my React app starts without React-Router.

Here is a bit of context. I have a sort of micro front-end apps. I am using Iframes for individual apps and the wrapper app passes a few query strings in the Iframe URL when we click on a menu in the wrapper app. The wrapper app uses React-Router but none of the child apps use it. For development now I have to start individual applets and add the query params manually in the URL. To save some time I am trying to hardcode a few params for the development environment while React starts.

Like we can set up the PORT, is there any way in the npm start command to handle this?

My current start command `"start": "set PORT=41100 && env-cmd -f .env.dev react-scripts start",`

**What I tried**
I tried using the BROWSER and BROWSER_ARGS in the command but had no success. Not sure whether this is how it is used.

`"start": "set PORT=41100 && set BROWSER=Chrome && set BROWSER_ARGS=\"param=val\" && env-cmd -f .env.dev react-scripts start",`

A working option is to add a bit of script in the `index.jsx`,

`if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" && !window.location.search) window.location.search = "abc=xyz";`

If anyone knows how to handle it in the NPM scripts somehow, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

React is "just a framework and methodology running in javascript" when running in the browser, so you can do literally anything you want "in React without X" because you can do anything you'd want to do in a browser using JS, and you *always* get JS =)

If you need the URL updated to include query args, you can do that with [history.replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState). If you need to read them in, you want [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). The question with React is mostly "when do you do this", to which the answer is typically "in `componentDidMount`, in whatever component that you designed to have all the information necessary".

(Or as a useEffect in a function component, but since that triggers on ever render(), using a class component just makes things so much easier in cases like these).

Comment: Thank you. I totally agree that any javascript will work. I was trying to avoid adding scripts for this purpose. I can add a simple script as you said and get it working. In fact I got it working. `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" && !window.location.search)
  window.location.search = "abc=xyz";` . This adds the query params in the URL.

Comment: What do you mean with "adding scripts" - literally your entire React codebase is scripts. How is "adding the code you need" any different? As for the code in  your comment: remember that `process` does not exist in the browser, and `window` does not exist in Node context. Before you reference properties in them, always remember to check whether things exist. In modern context that means using `globalThis.process?.env?.NODE_ENV` and `globalThis?.location?.search` (using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining))

Comment: "Adding scripts" means adding some more lines of code to already present react code. I needed `window` in the browser and `process` in the node. When you build react code `process?.env?.NODE_ENV` will be replaced by the "production" string. In dev mode, it will be "development". This code will be ignored in the production build and still work in my dev. And yes, `globalThis` and existence check are important. Thank you.

Comment: Still don't get why you expected magic here - if you need to do things, you need to write code to do those things, that's how programming works. The idea of "not wanting to add lines of code" is generally the worst outset to be programming in: you _want_ to add as much code as necessary, and you want to follow a very simple process: (1) _make it work_, (2) improve your code once it works. Sure, maybe you can find a way to reduce the code footprint later on, but your first priority is to make things work, whether that means more code or not. Once you have that done do the rest

Comment: Magic is, if this is possible through NPM scripts in package.json, instead of writing code in my codebase. As a react starter properties somehow if I can set a few query params. The original question was about that not how I can do it through writing a few lines of code in my codebase. Now you may ask, what's the difference. I am just curious.

Comment: Oh in that case: "sure, just install react-history and then manually trigger it instead of using react-router" but even adding an npm package _still_ adds more code because you're still going to need to require it in your own code and configure it there. Setting and parsing URLs are both essentially one-liners, wanting an npm package for it is going to bloat your bundle _far_ more than if you write it yourself in this case (Which is an important consideration: just because you write less code, doesn't mean your client bundle will also be smaller. That's almost never the case)